# binary format of a PeakTech 1330 oscilloscope

Tags: binaryfiles, channel, volt, sample-rate, oscilloscope

Does anybody know the binary format of a PeakTech 1330 oscilloscope?

What I do know:
The first 32 byte seem to be a header describing the instrument.
The last 94 byte seem to describe the setting (gain, time scale, channel used ...) - but I have no clue of the coding.
In the middle it looks like a dump of the ADC samples (1 byte per sample)

What I need:
I want to read the scaling from the last 94 bytes to give the data a physical meaning in Volts and Seconds. (multiplying ADC values with gain factors and sample number with time scale).

Comment: possible tips on reverse engineering the signal  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227408/reverse-engineering-a-serial-protocol-with-a-scope/227425

Comment: My problem is not reverse engineering a bit stream. I already have the complete file.

Answer (score 1):

1. byte 0..9: headder holding device name
2. byte 23..26: record length (total), MSbyte at 23
3. byte 28..31: data field length (MSB at byte 28)
4. byte 32..end_data: ADC sample values (-128..+127)
5. end_data+1+x
6. x=6..9: number of sample points per channel
7. x=17: time scale (2ns/div=x00..100s/div=x20)
8. x=18..21: trigger offset, MSB first, 1LSB=0.2ns
9. x=26: length of channel description (n*67byte. n=number of channels)
10. x=27..29: channel name (CH1, CH2, CH3...)
11. x=38..41: trigger delay
12. x=42..45: samples in visible range
13. x=46..49: number of samples outside visible range
    13: x=62..65: totqal number of samples
14. x=73: vertical offset. LSB=0.04div.
15. x=77: sensitivity (20mV/div=x00..50V/div=x0A
16. x=82..85: measured frequency 32bit float big endian (sign is in byte 82, Mantissa LSB is byte 85